# UserControl in xCode

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, storyboard, xcode5

I'm creating the UI layer for an application. I'm new to iOS development and there is one thing I do not undearstand. I want to create a part of UI and move it throug different 'pages' - I want to have the same functionality in different pages. Sth like UserControls in WPF. It seems for me to be the basic functionality of an interface builder - but I can't find it anywhere. What should I do to move a part of the UI to different pages? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work when you use storyboards. With normal xibs this is quite easy. Just load the same xib in different view controllers.

And yes, this proves that one should not use storyboards in product code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I'm suprised this is the way it works. I just have one more idea. Is there a possibility, that more than one ViewController responds to one page? I think I could draw the same buttons on every page but I wish I could have just one class that does the logic for every single part of UI copied to other pages.

Answer (score 1):

Just create own subclass of `UIView` and use it in various parts of your application